# Why is tcp_tw_reuse turned off by default?

Tags: linux, tcp

I had an issue where I was running out of connections due to all of them being in a TIME_WAIT state.  Setting the timeout to 1s still caused the issue.  We use a load balancer so I went with tcp_tw_reuse instead of recycle.  I am going to release code that requires the use of tcp_tw_reuse being turned on.

However, I assume there is some potential for negative impact with tcp_tw_reuse, but I can't think of what it might be.  Does anyone know why this isn't turned on by default in Linux installations?

Or, can anyone list any potential negative impacts?  I assume this doesn't have any impact on the system until it runs out of connections, at which point the need for this seems obvious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saw a great article on this today, that provides a really in depth answer that I thought anyone that ran across this question should have:

http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html

After reviewing it, it looks like the change I made to use tcp_tw_reuse doesn't even impact incoming connections, so it appears that my original solution was a fruitless change on my part.

Answer (score 1):

The TIME_WAIT state is an integral part of TCP. It is a security/data integrity measure to prevent data from two sequential connections between the same port numbers from getting mixed up. You should certainly *not* mess around with it. The only problem it can cause is a bind error when creating outbound connections. It is ultimately caused by applications that should be using connection pooling and aren't.